# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sleep'` as specified in the title of this question and I cannot figure out why it is throwing that error message.

**Countdown Timer.py**

```python
import time, datetime

Year = 2020
Month = 12
Day = 24
Hour = 23
Minute = 18
Second = 50

while True:
    Datetime = datetime.datetime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second)
    diff = Datetime - datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = str(diff)

    days, not_useful, time = diff.split()

    Day1 = days + " " + "Day" # Day

    print(Day1)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: try adding  `print(time)` in line 2 and line 14. recognizing any difference ;-) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you locally erased the variable `time` that contained the module with a string. Here is a correct code:

```
import time, datetime

Year = 2020
Month = 12
Day = 24
Hour = 23
Minute = 18
Second = 50

while True:
    Datetime = datetime.datetime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second)
    diff = Datetime - datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = str(diff)

    days, not_useful, time_str = diff.split()

    Day1 = days + " " + "Day" # Day

    print(Day1)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
days, not_useful, time = diff.split()
```

here you will have 'time' as string. change verb name...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `Time` as a variable in your code:

```
time = diff.split()
```

and the above line is locally overwriting the variable `time`in the time-module.

Try using a different variable:

```
time_1 = diff.split()
```

Comment: You said the same thing that was said as the accepted answer. That's the reason I downvoted your answer. I am well aware that you are a new contributor to the site, which is great! Just for future reference make sure that you just don't copy what's said in an answer already (especially when it's an accepted one) unless you can build upon something that someone already said. Happy answering :-)