# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I am getting AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'sleep' as specified in the title of this question and I cannot figure out why it is throwing that error message. this is automation script which will automatic post facebook. if someone know what's wrong with my code my tell me. code is here

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import traceback
import string
import xlrd

#taking inputs from user-----------------------------------
delay=input('Set Time: ')
limit=input('Set Post Limit: ')
valuee=limit
count=0
start=0
end=valuee
#----------------------------------------------------------


#open file for taking multiple accounts-------------------
f=open('Accounts.csv')
data=f.readlines()
i=0
for value in data:
values=value.split(',')

password=values[1]
user_name=values[0]

#Condition for next URLs--------------------------
if count>=1:
    start=limit
    end=start + valuee
    limit=end
count+=1
#-----------------------------------------------
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #going to chrome options
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2 #turn off all notifications
         ,"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2} #disable images 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) # passing paramaters to chrome
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
try:
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
    time.sleep(2)

    #puting userName and password---------------------------------------------------------
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#email').send_keys(user_name)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#pass').send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/pages/?category=your_pages')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1vgt.ellipsis._349g a').click()
    pageUrl=driver.current_url
    raw_input('>>')
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raw_input('Something Wrong..! please hit Enter >>\n')
    driver.quit()
    continue

#file for report-----
report=open('Report/'+user_name+'.csv','w')


#reading file of excel--------------------------------------------------------------------
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('links.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

#print commands:
print '\n******************** Auto Posting Start ********************\n'
#print 'Using Proxy:',proxy
print 'Using Email:',user_name

for row in range(start, end):
    driver.get(pageUrl)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        #title=value=sheet.cell(row, 0).value
        disc=value=sheet.cell(row, 0).value
        try:

            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/%s);" % 5)
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1hib._4bl9').click()
                time.sleep(4)
            except:
                pass

            try:
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.notranslate._5rpu').send_keys(disc)
                time.sleep(3)
            except:
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._4h98.navigationFocus').send_keys(disc)
                time.sleep(3)

            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft').click()
            time.sleep(6)

            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(4)

            #get latest post url---------------------------
            for elem in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._5pcq'):
                try:
                    tim=elem.find_element_by_css_selector('._5ptz.timestamp.livetimestamp')
                    time=tim.text
                    if time=='Just now':
                        print'great'
                        href=elem.get_attribute('href')
                        print href
                        raw_input('>>')
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
                except:
                    continue

            print 'Report Url:',href
            report.write(href+'\n')       
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            pass
        time.sleep(delay)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print'Urls Completed!'
        break

report.close()
driver.quit()
print'Thanks For Using..'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sleep'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506536/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-sleep)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you overwrote time with a string in below line

```
tim=elem.find_element_by_css_selector('._5ptz.timestamp.livetimestamp')
time=tim.text
if time=='Just now':
```

So time is no more a module it is just a unicode text. You need to rename that variable to something else